# problem installing libClang with cabal on minGW

Tags: windows, haskell, mingw, cabal

Who can help me installing libClang with cabal install? I do the following things:

1. Install haskell plattform
2. install minGW on my Windows 7 System
3. download `LLVM Binaries for Mingw32/x86` and `Clang Binaries for Mingw32/x86`
4. then I copy it to my minGW folder

when I try to start `cabal install libClang`, I always get the error:

```
clang library not found.
if the library is present, ensure it is aviable
on the lib search path (export LDFLAGS=...)
```

This is the point I don't know what to do, I tried a lot of things: adding paths to PATH, LDFLAGS and LD_LIB_LIBRARY_PATH with no success.

Perhaps someone had the same problem and could tell me what to do

**------- EDIT :**

I now made some improvements:

1. installed haskell plattform
2. only installed MSYS like in the blog post (found in the comments http://blog.johantibell.com/2011/01/setting-up-haskell-development.html)

but now when I start cabal install libClang I get:

```
llvm-config not found
```

where should I copy my `LLVM Binaries for Mingw32/x86` and `Clang Binaries for Mingw32/x86` ?

**------ EDIT 2 :**

i put the `LLVM Binaries for Mingw32/x86` and `Clang Binaries for Mingw32/x86` to haskell folder and also to MSYS

now it was successfull.

**when i use it now i get a error:**
unknown symbol _clang_toggleCrashRecovery (C:\Users\Foo\AppData\Roadming\cabal\LibClang-0.0.9\ghc-7.0.3\HSLibClang-0.0.9.o)

what to do?

Comment: a) You don't have to install mingw, it's included with GHC in $GHCDIR/mingw. Just add that directory to PATH.

Comment: b) You need to install MSYS though, since you want to run configure scripts

Comment: Try compiling a C program that uses libClang first (using the version of gcc bundled with GHC).

Comment: Have you read http://blog.johantibell.com/2011/01/setting-up-haskell-development.html ?

Comment: made some edits and installed only MSYS, please have a look